# i want to write a visual studio extension to access redmine issues. how would you recommend doing this?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, add-in, visual-studio-addins

i want to write a visual studio extension to access redmine issues.  how would you recommend doing this?  I thought about trying to use the work item system that already exists in visual studio with TFS, but I'm not sure that'd be the best approach or if that's even necessary.

Is it possible to populate work items through a visual studio extension and provide access to those items without an actual TFS server?

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write a custom Package and use the [IVSTaskList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivstasklist%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) service to output stuff from Redmine into the task window. You can also build your own [ToolWindowPane](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.toolwindowpane%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) (override [ToolWindowPane.Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.windowpane.window.aspx) to return a WinForm usercontrol) to do anything you want.

I'm not sure that the TFS bindings are available on all machines, so I wouldn't try and hook into them.

Answer (score 0):

Check out a simple Visual Studio extension that displays Redmine issues as tasks in Task List tool window:

https://redminetasklist.codeplex.com/